# Apache HttpClient created by PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager can not close

Tags: java, httpclient, connection-pooling, apache-httpclient-4.x

I use PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager create httpClient, when I close http client, it will shutdown PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.

Why is it designed like this?

Is the CloseableHttpClient need close?

```java
package org.example.zk;

import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HTTPTest {

    private static PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();

    public static void req() throws IOException {
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setConnectionManager(connectionManager).build();
        try {
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://www.google.com");
            try (CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet)) {
                System.out.println(httpResponse.getStatusLine());
            }
        } finally {
            httpClient.close();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
        connectionManager.setMaxTotal(100);
        connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(10);
        req();
        System.out.println("end");
    }
}
```

trace the thread stack:

```
shutdown:410, PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager (org.apache.http.impl.conn)
close:1248, HttpClientBuilder$2 (org.apache.http.impl.client)
close:201, InternalHttpClient (org.apache.http.impl.client)
req:27, HTTPTest (org.example.zk)
main:37, HTTPTest (org.example.zk)
```